# Serving gzipped content from django

Tags: django, http, gzip

I'm trying to serve a gzipped version of a text/html page in Django, but Firefox is telling me there's a content encoding error.

NOTES:

- I realize this is not a best practice and I'm most likely going to use mod_gzip.  This is just a learning exercise to understand what's going on.
- I know about the Django gzip middleware-- it has problems with binary files.

Here's my code:

```
rendered_page =  zlib.compress(template.render(context).encode('utf-8'))

response = HttpResponse(rendered_page)
response['Content-Encoding'] = 'gzip'
response['Content-Length'] = len(rendered_page)
return response
```

Am I missing something here?  Is it possible that the content length is wrong?  Are there additional headers I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: BTW... if you're using Apache 2.x, have a peek at mod_deflate... it's a bit more advanced than mod_zip.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`zlib` is a bit too low-level for this purpose. Here's how the GZip middleware itself does it (see compress_string in [django.utils.text.py](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/text.py)):

```
import cStringIO, gzip
zbuf = cStringIO.StringIO()
zfile = gzip.GzipFile(mode='wb', compresslevel=6, fileobj=zbuf)
zfile.write(template.render(context).encode('utf-8'))
zfile.close()

compressed_content = zbuf.getvalue()
response = HttpResponse(compressed_content)
response['Content-Encoding'] = 'gzip'
response['Content-Length'] = str(len(compressed_content))
return response
```

GZip uses zlib, but on its own zlib produces content that's improperly encoded for a browser seeing 'gzip' as the content encoding. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 98):

You could also simply use [Django's GZip Middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.gzip):

Either by enabling the middleware in settings.py by adding:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    "django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware",
    ...
)
```

Or do it before you return a particular response. In your views.py, dec would be the handler for a certain  url

```
from django.middleware.gzip import GZipMiddleware

gzip_middleware = GZipMiddleware()

 def dec(request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return gzip_middleware.process_response(request, response)
        return dec
```

NOTE: You should be **certain** you are not subject to side-channel attacks before using GZip middleware.

> Warning
>
> Security researchers recently revealed that when compression
> techniques (including GZipMiddleware) are used on a website, the site
> may become exposed to a number of possible attacks. Before using
> GZipMiddleware on your site, you should consider very carefully
> whether you are subject to these attacks. **If you’re in any doubt about
> whether you’re affected, you should avoid using GZipMiddleware.** For
> more details, see the the BREACH paper (PDF) and breachattack.com.

Also:

> Changed in Django 1.10: In older versions, Django’s CSRF protection
> mechanism was vulnerable to BREACH attacks when compression was used.
> This is no longer the case, but you should still take care not to
> compromise your own secrets this way.

Comment: Please note current security warnings regarding the gzip middleware: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.gzip

Comment: When I tried this, I got `No module named middlware.gzip`. Adding `@gzip_page`on top of my view methods worked though. Any idea what the problem is? Am on Django 1.9

Comment: @hd1 you should use strings to specify a middleware class, not the class/module itself. So instead of `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware,]` you should do: `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ["django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware",]`

Comment: As of 1.10, Django includes methods to mitigate the BREACH attack, resolving the security issue Tobias highlighted above. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/middleware/

Comment: Due to security issues and as remarked above, I'd go with the decorator approach.

Comment: What is the meaning of 2 consecutive return statements in the same method?

Answer (score 30):

If you're gzipping single page, not for all pages, you can use **gzip_page** decorator instead of GzipMiddleware.

```
from django.views.decorators.gzip import gzip_page

@gzip_page
def viewFunc(request):
  return HttpResponse("hello"*100)
```

Reference here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/decorators/#module-django.views.decorators.gzip

Comment: By the way, this is still valid for Django 1.11.x and for a Django problem, a Django solution should be the accepted answer IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of others finding this question and who are using nginx, this SO worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41820704/4533488

Basically turning gzip on in the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file did all the compression handling for me. On the client-side, most modern browsers automatically handle extracting (uncompressing) the data when receiving it - sweet!

Here is the nginx.conf file settings:

```
    http {

        #... other settings ...#

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    }
```

Comment: Be aware that this only compresses HTTP 1.1 but not HTTP 1.0, which might or might not be an issue depending on your application and target audience. AFAIK there is no simple solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you need it for a single page and you are using class based views, use this:

```
gzip_middleware = GZipMiddleware()

class GZipMixin(object):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(GZipMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return gzip_middleware.process_response(request, response)
```

Then in your actual view:

```
class MyView(GZipMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         #return your response
```

Answer (score 1):

If you compress your data with `zlib`, you have to set `Content-Encoding` to `deflate`, not `gzip`.

```
rendered_page =  zlib.compress(template.render(context).encode('utf-8'))

response = HttpResponse(rendered_page)
response['Content-Encoding'] = 'deflate'
response['Content-Length'] = len(rendered_page)
return response
```

> ## [Content-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding)
>
> (...)
>
> **deflate**
>
> Using the zlib structure (defined in RFC 1950) with the deflate compression algorithm (defined in RFC 1951).