# Compress JSON payload in Django for both request from client and response from server (REST API).

Tags: python, json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am wondering if there's a way to compress the JSON payload I have to send every time with many repetitive field names. While [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823422/compressing-the-response-payload-in-django-rest) is only about compressing the response, I would like to know how to compress the JSON payload from client (may be a mobile app) as well. Also, I want to know how do I convert the compressed JSON file back to its original structure both on client and server side.

A detailed answer with the steps will be appreciated.

I am using `djangorestframework==2.4.4` with `Django==1.7.7` for the APIs.

Comment: use shorter JSON property names?

Answer (score 1):

From the client-side different tools may have done it differently. A simple implementation for a `python-requests` based client is done in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38866506/2656621).

But as for the decompression, I think it is better to be done at webserver level, just the same as what you did for response compression. It seems that there is no built-in configuration for Nginx but somebody has done [sort of Lua](http://www.pataliebre.net/howto-make-nginx-decompress-a-gzipped-request.html#.Xbg2ftGhU8p) to do the decompression before passing the request to the upstream.

Another - may be less efficient - solution would be to do the decompression in the very first Django middleware like the following:

```py
import gzip


class SimpleMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
       self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):

        # check the headers if you are writing a versatile API
        # decompress the request body
        request._body = gzip.decompress(request.body)
        # fill the request stream in case you're using something like django-rest-framework
        request._stream = BytesIO(request.body)

        response = self.get_response(request)

        return response
```

Also, you have to configure your middleware as the very first middleware:

```py
# in Django settings

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'python path to our new custom middleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Here are the references:

1. [Stackoverflow post on how to send gzipped reqeusts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425901/can-i-post-data-with-python-requests-lib-with-http-gzip-or-deflate-compression),
2. [Python 3 gzip documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html),
3. [Server fault thread on request body decompression](https://serverfault.com/questions/334215/how-do-i-configure-nginx-to-accept-gzip-requests),
4. [Django middleware reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/).