# How to compress a field of django model?

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs

One of my models has a field where I store very large arrays. My frontend app has to load all of them at once which makes the request response a bit slow. I was thinking of compressing the arrays in the backend and decompressing in my react frontend application, is it possible?

Comment: You could use [`gzip`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.gzip) since your browser knows how to decompress it automatically as long as the headers are correct (which the middleware sets).

Comment: Could you please provide me with an example? What headers should be correct? And how is it automatically decompressed? Does the response body already return the matrix?

Comment: Consider caching as well.

Comment: How are you downloading this array from your app? You could consider using a streaming http response if it is a file like object

Comment: In Django, you can add GZip middleware to your app by adding the line `'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware'` to the `MIDDLEWARE` list in `settings.py`.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1864377/4509338).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to compress data on the backend in Django and then decompress it in your React frontend application. This can help reduce the size of data transferred over the network and improve the speed of your application.

**Backend (Django)**

```
import gzip
from django.http import HttpResponse

def compressed_data(request):
    data_to_compress = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  # Your large array

    # Compress the data
    compressed_data = gzip.compress(bytes(str(data_to_compress), 'utf-8'))

    # Return the compressed data as a response
    response = HttpResponse(compressed_data, content_type='application/octet-stream')
    response['Content-Encoding'] = 'gzip'
    return response
```

**Front end**

```
fetch('/api/compressed_data')
  .then(response => {
    // Check if the response is compressed
    if (response.headers.get('Content-Encoding') === 'gzip') {
      // Decompress the data using a library like pako
      return response.arrayBuffer().then(data => pako.inflate(new Uint8Array(data), { to: 'string' }));
    } else {
      return response.text();
    }
  })
  .then(data => {
    // Process the decompressed or uncompressed data
    console.log(data);
  });
```

[pako library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pako)